# Generate instance in column with duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','a','b','a','b','c']})

    A
0   a
1   a
2   b
3   a
4   b
5   c
```

Expected Output:

```
     A
0   a.1
1   a.2
2   b.1
3   a.3
4   b.2
5   c.1
```

Need generate instance for duplicates in the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with `add` `1` and converting to strings:

```
df_1['A'] = df_1['A'] + '.' + df_1.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Or use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df_1['A'] = df_1['A'].str.cat(df_1.groupby('A').cumcount().add(1).astype(str), sep='.')
```

---

```
print (df_1)
     A
0  a.1
1  a.2
2  b.1
3  a.3
4  b.2
5  c.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1['A']=df_1['A']+'.'+(df_1.groupby('A').cumcount()+1).astype(str)



    A
0  a.1
1  a.2
2  b.1
3  a.3
4  b.2
5  c.1
```